# Batch printing PDFs different amount of times

Tags: print-design, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Is there a way to do a batch print where you can specify how often the respective pdfs have to be printed.  like print the first pdf 100 times, the second 80 and the third only 5 times.
Maybe with an acrobat plugin or someting?